# Discrete State Space Representation of a second order system

Tags: matrices, control-theory

A second order disturbance-based model can be represented as follows:

$$\ddot{y}=f(y,\dot{y},w,t)+bu(t)$$

where $f(y,\dot{y},w,t)$ is generalized disturbance. This can be represented in continuous time state as:

$$\dot{x}=Ax(t)+Bu(t)+E\dot{f}(t)$$
$$y(t)=Cx(t)$$

where, $A=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$, $B=\begin{bmatrix}0\\b\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $C=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $E=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}y\\\dot{y}\\f\end{bmatrix}$.

When the above state space equation is discretized, we can get the following:

$$x(k+1)=\Phi x(k)+\Gamma u(k)+E_df(k+1)$$
$$y(k)=Cx(k)$$

My question is,

1. Is the term $f(k+1)$ for discretized $\dot{f}(t)$ correct or should it be $f(k)$?
2. How do you determine the term $E_d$ associated with $\dot{f}(t)$ using zero order hold?

Comment: The system of ODEs as it is written above is incorrect. You $A$ should be $[2\times 2]$ and all vectors $[2\times 1]$. You write it as a descriptor system which is an unnecessary complication.

Comment: Your state space model cannot represent the actual system. Because $f$ is not independent of the states. You need to linearize it around an equilibrium point before discretization.

Comment: @obareey, I am trying to design a discrete extended state observer (DESO). Therefore, generalized disturbance $f(\dot{y},\ddot{y},w,t)$ is expressed as an extended state. Basically $f(\dot{y},\ddot{y},w,t)$ is a combination of internal dynamics $g(\dot{y},\ddot{y},t)$ and external disturbance $w$. Following is the paper that I am trying to follow to design the DESO. 

R. Miklosovic, A. Radke and Zhiqiang Gao, "Discrete implementation and generalization of the extended state observer," 2006 American Control Conference, Minneapolis, MN, 2006, pp. 6 pp.-.
doi: 10.1109/ACC.2006.1656547

Answer (score 1):

In continuous time, you assume that $\dot{f}$ exists and can be written as a function $\xi(t):=\dot{f}(t)$. Then you can write your model as $$\dot{x}=Ax + Bu + E\xi$$ making the difference between the states and external inputs more explicit.

Following the same idea, in discrete time you have to assume the existence of a function $\Delta(k)$ such that $f(k+1)=f(k)+T_s\Delta(k)$, where $T_s$ is the sampling time. Then your model becomes $$x(k+1) = \Phi x(k) + \Gamma u(k) + E_d \Delta(k),$$ where the last line in $\Phi$ is $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $E_d = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & T_s\end{bmatrix}^\top$.

Obviously, a good guess for $\Delta(k)$ is $$\Delta(k) = \frac{1}{T_s}\int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}}\dot{f}(s)ds.$$

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense. But I have seen in some literature, that the matrix $E$ needs to be discretized using the equation $E_d$=$\int_0^{T_s}$ $e^{A\tau}$$E$$d$$\tau$ which does not make sense to me.

Comment: @DonB This equation is correct when you transform a СT system $\dot{f}(t)=A_f f(t)+E\xi(t)$,where in your case $\xi=\dot{f}$, and you assume that $\xi(t)$ is constant on the interval $[t,\,t+T_s]$ (a zero-order hold). Note that in your case you have $A_f=0$ and $\int_{t}^{t+T_s}e^{A_f \tau} E d\tau = \int_{t}^{t+T_s}E d\tau = T_sE$, that is exactly $[0,\ 0,\ T_s]^\top$. Note also that if you assume $\dot{f}(t)$ being a constant on the interval, then $\Delta(k) =\frac{1}{T_s}\int_{t_k}^{t_k+T_s} \dot{f}(\tau)d\tau=  \dot{f}(t_k)$.

Answer (score 1):

The analytical solution of the differential equation is as follows:

$$ x(t) = e^{At} x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t e^{A(t-\tau)} B u(\tau) d\tau + \int_{t_0}^t e^{A(t-\tau)} E \dot{f}(\tau) d\tau $$

To discretize this system we have to find the solution at $(k+1) T$ (assuming $t_0=0$). So,

$$\begin{align}
x((k+1) T) &= e^{A(k+1) T} x(0) + \int_{0}^{(k+1) T} e^{A((k+1) T-\tau)} B u(\tau) d\tau + \int_{0}^{(k+1) T} e^{A((k+1) T-\tau)} E \dot{f}(\tau) d\tau \\
&= e^{A(k+1) T} x(0) + \int_{0}^{kT} e^{A((k+1) T-\tau)} B u(\tau) d\tau + \int_{kT}^{(k+1) T} e^{A((k+1) T-\tau)} B u(\tau) d\tau + \\
&\phantom{=} \int_{0}^{kT} e^{A((k+1) T-\tau)} E \dot{f}(\tau) d\tau + \int_{kT}^{(k+1) T} e^{A((k+1) T-\tau)} E \dot{f}(\tau) d\tau \\
&= e^{AT} x(kT) + \int_{kT}^{(k+1) T} e^{A((k+1) T-\tau)} B u(\tau) d\tau + \int_{kT}^{(k+1) T} e^{A((k+1) T-\tau)} E \dot{f}(\tau) d\tau
\end{align}$$

Define $\eta = (k+1) T-\tau$. Then,
$$x((k+1) T) = e^{AT} x(kT) + \int_{0}^{T} e^{A\eta} B u((k+1) T-\eta) d\eta + \int_{0}^{T} e^{A\eta} E \dot{f}((k+1) T-\eta) d\eta $$

Assuming zero-order hold on $u(t)$ we can write $u((k+1) T-\eta) = u(kT)$ to obtain the well-known discretization result
$$x((k+1) T) = e^{AT} x(kT) + \left( \int_{0}^{T} e^{A\eta} d\eta \right) B u(kT)  + \int_{0}^{T} e^{A\eta} E \dot{f}((k+1) T-\eta) d\eta $$
Obviously, if you have further information on $\dot{f}$, you can go further. But taking the average of $\dot{f}$ gives you only an approximation, which gets worse when $T$ gets bigger.

---

Edit: I've misread the question. The above calculations is true only when $f$ is independent from the states. Otherwise one needs to linearize the system around an equilibrium point.

Answer (score 1):

Your dynamics would be equivalent to

$$
\dot{x}(t) = A\,x(t) + B^*\,u^*(t), \tag{1}
$$

with

$$
B^* = 
\begin{bmatrix}
B & E
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
u^*(t) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
u(t) \\ \dot{f}(t)
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{2}
$$

This more standard expression for a continuous linear state space model has a known solution for discretization using zero order hold (so $u^*(t)=u^*[k]\,\forall\ k\,T\leq t<(k+1)T$ with $T$ the time step size), [namely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization#Discretization_of_linear_state_space_models)

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_d & B^*_d \\ 0 & I
\end{bmatrix} = 
e^{\begin{bmatrix}
A & B^* \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}T}, \tag{3}
$$

such that

$$
x[k+1] = A_d\,x[k] + B^*_d\,u^*[k]. \tag{4}
$$

Using this for your system yields

$$
A_d = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & T & \frac{1}{2}T^2 \\
0 & 1 & T \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
B^*_d = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{b}{2}T^2 & \frac{1}{6}T^3 \\
b\,T & \frac{1}{2}T^2 \\
0 & T
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{5}
$$

If you want to express it using $f[k+1]$ instead of $\dot{f}[k]$ you can use that from zero order hold one gets

$$
f[k+1] = f[k] + T\,\dot{f}[k] \leftrightarrow \dot{f}[k] = \frac{f[k+1] - f[k]}{T}. \tag{6}
$$

Substituting $(6)$ into $(4)$ yields

$$
x[k+1] = \hat{A}\,x[k] + \hat{B}\,v[k], \tag{7}
$$

with

$$
v[k] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
u[k] \\ f[k+1]
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
\hat{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & T & \frac{1}{3}T^2 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2}T \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
\hat{B} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{b}{2}T^2 & \frac{1}{6}T^2 \\
b\,T & \frac{1}{2}T \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{8}
$$